# gcp pubsub-lite subscription python "A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition" error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

I am using the python pubsublite client(async version) for subscribing from pubsub-lite.
The topic has 10 partitions, I am creating 5 clients at the same time so each client gets messages from two partitions(its working), but sometimes I am getting errors in some of the subscribers(this is not happening always)

```json
{
    "time": 1662717414,
    "level": "ERROR",
    "message": "Future exception was never retrieved\nfuture: <Future finished exception=Aborted('A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition.')>",
    "type": "applog",
    "name": "asyncio",
    "exc_info": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py\", line 102, in _wrapped_aiter\n    async for response in self._call:  # pragma: no branch\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py\", line 326, in _fetch_stream_responses\n    await self._raise_for_status()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py\", line 236, in _raise_for_status\n    raise _create_rpc_error(await self.initial_metadata(), await\ngrpc.aio._call.AioRpcError: <AioRpcError of RPC that terminated with:\n\tstatus = StatusCode.ABORTED\n\tdetails = \"A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition.\"\n\tdebug_error_string = \"UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.253.63.95:443 {created_time:\"2022-09-09T09:56:48.360743382+00:00\", grpc_status:10, grpc_message:\"A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition.\"}\"\n>\n\nThe above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/retrying_connection.py\", line 100, in _run_loop\n    await self._loop_connection(\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/retrying_connection.py\", line 154, in _loop_connection\n    await self._read_queue.put(await read_task)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/permanent_failable.py\", line 76, in await_unless_failed\n    raise self._failure_task.exception()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/gapic_connection.py\", line 71, in read\n    raise self.error()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/gapic_connection.py\", line 66, in read\n    return await self.await_unless_failed(response_it.__anext__())\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/permanent_failable.py\", line 75, in await_unless_failed\n    return await task\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py\", line 105, in _wrapped_aiter\n    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(rpc_error) from rpc_error\ngoogle.api_core.exceptions.Aborted: 409 A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition. [reason: \"DUPLICATE_SUBSCRIBER_CONNECTIONS\"\ndomain: \"pubsublite.googleapis.com\"\n]"
}
```

`exc_info` value pretty-printed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py", line 102, in _wrapped_aiter
    async for response in self._call:  # pragma: no branch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py", line 326, in _fetch_stream_responses
    await self._raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py", line 236, in _raise_for_status
    raise _create_rpc_error(await self.initial_metadata(), await
grpc.aio._call.AioRpcError: <AioRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.ABORTED
        details = "A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:172.253.63.95:443 {created_time:"2022-09-09T09:56:48.360743382+00:00", grpc_status:10, grpc_message:"A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition."}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/retrying_connection.py", line 100, in _run_loop
    await self._loop_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/retrying_connection.py", line 154, in _loop_connection
    await self._read_queue.put(await read_task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/permanent_failable.py", line 76, in await_unless_failed
    raise self._failure_task.exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/gapic_connection.py", line 71, in read
    raise self.error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/gapic_connection.py", line 66, in read
    return await self.await_unless_failed(response_it.__anext__())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsublite/internal/wire/permanent_failable.py", line 75, in await_unless_failed
    return await task
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py", line 105, in _wrapped_aiter
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(rpc_error) from rpc_error
google.api_core.exceptions.Aborted: 409 A second subscriber connected with the same SubscriberId and topic partition. [reason: "DUPLICATE_SUBSCRIBER_CONNECTIONS"
domain: "pubsublite.googleapis.com"
]
```

Editing to add code used:

```
import asyncio

from google.cloud.pubsublite.cloudpubsub import AsyncSubscriberClient
from google.cloud.pubsublite.types import (
    CloudRegion,
    CloudZone,
    FlowControlSettings,
    SubscriptionPath,
)
from google.oauth2 import service_account


class AsyncTimedIterable:
    def __init__(self, iterable, poll_timeout=90):
        class AsyncTimedIterator:
            def __init__(self):
                self._iterator = iterable.__aiter__()

            async def __anext__(self):
                try:
                    result = await asyncio.wait_for(
                        self._iterator.__anext__(), int(poll_timeout)
                    )
                    if not result:
                        raise StopAsyncIteration
                    return result

                except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
                    raise e

        self._factory = AsyncTimedIterator

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self._factory()


# TODO add project info below
location = CloudZone(CloudRegion("region"), "zone")

subscription_path = SubscriptionPath("project_number", location, "subscription_id")

# TODO add service account details
gcp_creds = {}


async def async_receive_from_subscription(per_partition_count=100):
    # Configure when to pause the message stream for more incoming messages based on the
    # maximum size or number of messages that a single-partition subscriber has received,
    # whichever condition is met first.
    per_partition_flow_control_settings = FlowControlSettings(
        # 1,000 outstanding messages. Must be >0.
        messages_outstanding=per_partition_count,
        # 10 MiB. Must be greater than the allowed size of the largest message (1 MiB).
        bytes_outstanding=10 * 1024 * 1024,
    )

    async with AsyncSubscriberClient(
        credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_creds)
    ) as async_subscriber_client:
        message_iterator = await async_subscriber_client.subscribe(
            subscription_path,
            per_partition_flow_control_settings=per_partition_flow_control_settings,
        )

        timed_iter = AsyncTimedIterable(message_iterator, 90)
        async for message in timed_iter:
            yield message


async def main():
    async for message in async_receive_from_subscription(per_partition_count=100_000):
        print(message.data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The above code is the asyncio version of https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/samples/pubsublite-quickstart-subscriber which will do the same thing.

Comment: can you also add some code that actually generates this issue?

Comment: hi Edo Akse added code I used

Comment: Hi @VasuKandimalla, This error can occur when there is a backlog in partitions. If you are not using the latest version of [Pub/Sub Lite client](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-pubsublite/). Can you upgrade to the latest version and try?

Comment: I am using the latest version 1.4.3. Also having backlog messages in partitions is an ideal scenario, why will that cause an error?

Comment: Please see my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687323/gcp-pubsub-lite-subscription-python-authmetadataplugincallback-google-auth-t - this code will not work as written. That being said, is this an exception being thrown or an info log being printed to the console? Is the same error printed after fixing the code to be valid asyncio code?

Comment: @DanielCollins I have edited and added the exact working code now. The exception is not of log level INFO its of level ERROR. The same code has been running in my workloads for about a month, the ERROR is intermittent and we don't see it on every run

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.