# gcp pubsub-lite subscription python "AuthMetadataPluginCallback \"<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at " raised exception!" error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

I am using the python pubsublite client(async version) for subscribing from pubsub-lite.
I get the below error intermittently

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py\", line 89, in __call__
 self._metadata_plugin( 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py\", line 101, in __call__
 callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None) 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py\", line 87, in _get_authorization_headers
 self._credentials.before_request( 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py\", line 134, in before_request
 self.apply(headers) 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/credentials.py\", line 110, in apply
 _helpers.from_bytes(token or self.token) 
File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/_helpers.py\", line 130, in from_bytes 
raise ValueError(\"{0!r} could not be converted to unicode\".format(value))
ValueError: None could not be converted to unicode"
```

I don't use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable to specify credentials, instead I do as below(I don't want to write credentials to a file in aws host)

```
import asyncio

from google.cloud.pubsublite.cloudpubsub import AsyncSubscriberClient
from google.cloud.pubsublite.types import (
    CloudRegion,
    CloudZone,
    FlowControlSettings,
    SubscriptionPath,
)
from google.oauth2 import service_account


class AsyncTimedIterable:
    def __init__(self, iterable, poll_timeout=90):
        class AsyncTimedIterator:
            def __init__(self):
                self._iterator = iterable.__aiter__()

            async def __anext__(self):
                try:
                    result = await asyncio.wait_for(
                        self._iterator.__anext__(), int(poll_timeout)
                    )
                    if not result:
                        raise StopAsyncIteration
                    return result

                except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
                    raise e

        self._factory = AsyncTimedIterator

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self._factory()


# TODO add project info below
location = CloudZone(CloudRegion("region"), "zone")

subscription_path = SubscriptionPath("project_number", location, "subscription_id")

# TODO add service account details
gcp_creds = {}


async def async_receive_from_subscription(per_partition_count=100):
    # Configure when to pause the message stream for more incoming messages based on the
    # maximum size or number of messages that a single-partition subscriber has received,
    # whichever condition is met first.
    per_partition_flow_control_settings = FlowControlSettings(
        # 1,000 outstanding messages. Must be >0.
        messages_outstanding=per_partition_count,
        # 10 MiB. Must be greater than the allowed size of the largest message (1 MiB).
        bytes_outstanding=10 * 1024 * 1024,
    )

    async with AsyncSubscriberClient(
        credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_creds)
    ) as async_subscriber_client:
        message_iterator = await async_subscriber_client.subscribe(
            subscription_path,
            per_partition_flow_control_settings=per_partition_flow_control_settings,
        )

        timed_iter = AsyncTimedIterable(message_iterator, 90)
        async for message in timed_iter:
            yield message


async def main():
    async for message in async_receive_from_subscription(per_partition_count=100_000):
        print(message.data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

when I went through the files in stack trace I saw a code comment as below in file ``

```
# The plugin may be invoked on a thread created by Core, which will not
# have the context propagated. This context is stored and installed in
# the thread invoking the plugin.
```

Is it because the credentials I set are not being sent to another thread when it is created?

Comment: Hi @Vasu Kandimalla, Can you clarify your requirement? How are you using aws host?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar the application is deployed in aws ECS

Comment: @VasuKandimalla can you please provide a complete code sample? As-is the code will not run- all async keywords cannot be used at file scope but only inside an async context. In addition, the return type for subscribe is an AsyncIterator not an Iterator and must be used in an async for loop https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/

Comment: @DanielCollins I have added the code which works, you can run it as python file

Comment: Hi @VasuKandimalla, Can you try by using [Workload Identity Federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation)?